# WordPress + Gatsby Custom Rest Route Not Showing in GraphQL

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I'm fairly new to Gatsby and Im trying to build a site using WP as the content provider. I have a custom rest route built in WP 
`wp-json/lbt/v1/settings` 
and right now its just returning

```
{
"time_and_location": "Testing"
}
```

I cant seem to find out how to get that route to be available in graphQL for my Gatsby site. I have it set in my includedRoutes as

```
includedRoutes: [
 '/*/*/categories',
 '/*/*/posts',
 '/**/lbt/**',
 '/*/*/events',
 '/*/*/pages',
 '/*/*/media',
 '/*/*/tags',
 '/*/*/taxonomies',
 '/*/*/menus'
 ],
```

I also see this when I spin up Gatsby

```
-> wordpress__lbt_v1 fetched : 1
-> wordpress__lbt_settings fetched : 1
```

I've searched a lot of different sites, but I haven't managed to find anything. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add custom normalizer in "gatsby-config.js"
like

```
    ...
    plugins: [
    .....,
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
      options: {
         ......
         normalizers: normalizers => [ mapCustomApis,...normalizers],

      }
   }
......
```

add the "mapCustomApis" normalizer like

```
const mapCustomApis = {
  name: `mapCustomApis`,
  normalizer: function({ entities }) {

    return entities.reduce((acc, e) => {
        return acc.concat(e);
     
    }, []);
    }
}
```

- i replicated the code from https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/normalize.js#L102
  to support my custom Apis response
- make sure your normailzer is before the rest of the normalizers